# is there reasons why this code won't work on iphone and will on ipad?

Tags: uiimage, xcode6, collision-detection, imagenamed, cgrectintersectsrect

the code is:

```
if(CGRectIntersectsRect(icon1.frame, pig.frame) && icon1.image == [UIImage        imageNamed:@"BerryBlueberryIphone.png"]){
```

}

the code works in ipad but not iphone. spelling is correct for png file i can't seem to find out why it does not work. it was working before on all devices but i don't know if after updating Xcode there my be a setting affecting the line of code.

if more info is needed please let me know. would really like to figure this out today.

Comment: Try breaking the `if` into pieces and debugging which part isn't what you think it should be.

Comment: && icon1.image == [UIImage        imageNamed:@"BerryBlueberryIphone.png"] Is the part of the code that makes it invalid. Without it it works fine but I need it to recognize the image in the view. It was working now on iphone it doesn't but on the ipad it does. Any ideas why?

Comment: I have put more info on this question. Please take a look at it, any help will be great.         http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27930828/collision-not-working-on-iphone-just-ipad-xcode-6-1-1